# Destructuring tuple of tuple in closure

Tags: swift, closures, tuples

I can destructure a tuple of tuple easily:

```
let tt = (2, (3, 4))

let (a, (b, c)) = tt
b // => 3
```

I'd like to do the same when declaring a closure, for example I thought I could write:

```
[tt].map { (a, (b, c)) in
    // Use b
}
```

Xcode complains with "Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name".

Only way I got it to "work" was:

```
[tt].map { (a, tuple: (b: Int, c: Int)) in
    // Use tuple.b
}
```

This has two drawbacks I'd like to avoid:

- I need to use `tuple.b` instead of `b`
- I need to specify the types of `b` and `c`

BTW, my use case is that I want to do a `reduce` with index so I'm trying using `array.enumerate().reduce`

Comment: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/16190

Comment: I have started the thread and will submit a proposal next week. :)

Answer (score 2):

With an additional assignment line, you can assign the values in the array to `(a, (b, c))` to deconstruct the tuple:

```
let tt1 = (2, (3, 4))
let tt2 = (5, (6, 7))

[tt1, tt2].map { tt in
    let (a, (b, c)) = tt
    print(b)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 3
> 6
> ```

---

Alternatively:

```
[tt1, tt2].map {
    let (a, (b, c)) = $0
    print(b)
}
```

Comment: You could also stylistically change your second form to put the `let` on the same line of the brace, so it approaches the normal `myVar in` form.

Answer (score 1):

This satisfies your first requirement but still require you to add type annonation:

```
typealias TupleType = (a: Int, tuple: (b: Int, c: Int))

let tt: TupleType = (2, (3, 4))

[tt].map {
    print($0.tuple.b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

```
[tt].map { a, b in
    let (b, c) = b
    print(a, b, c)
}
```