# Call Array.reduce(_:_) from enumerated array

Tags: swift, reduce, swift3, enumerated

Normal `reduce` call:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, { cur, val in
  return val
})
```

Attempt at calling `reduce` from an `EnumeratedSequence<Array<Element>>`:

```
    [1,2,3].enumerated().reduce(0, { cur, (index, element) in
      return element
    })
  // Error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" (at initial reduce closure)
```

Comment: `let result = [1,2,3].enumerated().reduce(0) { $0 + $1.element }`

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1620.

Comment: Related: [Destructuring tuple of tuple in closure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37358171/2976878) & [Map or reduce with index in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28012205/2976878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `element` of the tuple with `val.element` and the `index` with `val.offset`:

```
let result = [1,2,3].enumerated().reduce(0, { cur, val in
    return val.element
})
```

---

Alternatively, you can use assignment to access the values in the tuple:

```
let result = [1,2,3].enumerated().reduce(0, { cur, val in
    let (index, element) = val
    return element
})
```

Comment: It's a slight restriction on Swift that you can't "expand" tuples in a closure's parameter list, which is the underlying problem with the code as per the question